# Corfu only working with elisp

Tags: corfu, autocompletion

I have tried a couple auto-completions engines on emacs, I had been working with `auto-complete` because it was the only one that I got working. I simply added some modes to a list and it was done:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'asm-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'go-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'tex-mode)
```

However, it always felt janky, and I never really liked the style.
Corfu on the other hands, works wonder but the problem is:

- It only works with elisp; how can I make it work with other programming buffers

I tried using dabbrev with the config on the [github page](https://github.com/minad/cape):

```
;; Use Dabbrev with Corfu!
(use-package dabbrev
  ;; Swap M-/ and C-M-/
  :bind (("M-/" . dabbrev-completion)
         ("C-M-/" . dabbrev-expand))
  ;; Other useful Dabbrev configurations.
  :custom
  (dabbrev-ignored-buffer-regexps '("\\.\\(?:pdf\\|jpe?g\\|png\\)\\'")))
```

But it doesn't follow my [TAB-GO](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/corfu.html#org89da541) config, and only "works" if I press `C-M-/`. However, it did auto-complete, so if I could add dabbrev's suggestions to Corfu, everything should work.
I am a complete Emacs novice, so I may have done things wrong. I have googled everywhere, but to no avail.

Comment: Only one question per post, please.

Comment: Edited. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

To get more of `corfu` package, you need to add [cape](https://github.com/minad/cape) completion at point extension and configure it as shown on that page. The function needed for programming languages is `cape-keyword` (the others are also useful to be added).

As for `asm-mode`, you must provide some more info - there is a built-in package, `asm-mode`, but if you need/use Intel x_332/x_64, there is on Melpa a better package, `masm-mode`, which will clobber with `asm-mode`. Also if you need some cross-assembler, there are better tools/packages to use, just tell what you need.

Keep in mind there is also the `lsp-mode` package, which can also do completion.
See [this page](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/).